# Investigating RAID-related issue that caused data loss while using LiveUSB

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, raid, data-loss

I recently tried to install Ubuntu on one of my hard drives and something went seriously wrong, resulting in 400+ GB of data being lost. Frustrated as I was, I've decided to try to find out what happened and perhaps alert others to this issue.

### Disks and partitions

The hard drive setup and partitioning scheme I had prior to trying Ubuntu is pictured here:

[image: Hard Disk setup prior to trying Ubuntu]

**Partition V** on **Disk 0** is a primary partition, while **W**, **X** and **Y** are logical, located inside an extended partition.

Windows 8 Pro x64 is installed on **Partition C**.

All partitions are NTFS formatted.

**Disks 0** and **1** are the exact same model. They have been used in a RAID configuration a couple of years back, but have since been reverted to regular configuration, serving as separate entities. BIOS settings are set to have them in IDE mode (can be configured as RAID or ACPI configuration, but isn't).

### The goal and the steps I took

I wanted to install Ubuntu on one of my partitions so to have a dual-boot configuration. Still in Windows environment, I moved data from **Partition V** to others, leaving it empty. I did not format or delete this partition, so it was left in NTFS format.

LiveUSB was created by following instructions on [Ubuntu website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) using *Pen Drive Linux* and ISO image downloaded from Ubuntu website (version 14.04 LTS).

After everything was ready, I rebooted from the USB and was prompted to either try or install Ubuntu. After checking out the apps and getting a general feel of the system, I've decided it's time to install it, so I clicked on *Install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS* shortcut on the desktop. Note that I **did not** run any applications that are remotely connected to partitioning or RAID configuring.

The installer prompted me with a couple of screens. It then asked me whether I'd like to replace Windows, erase the drive altogether (or similar, there were five options, I think). The last option was to configure partitioning manually, which I chose.

### First sign of problems and deletion of data

The next screen prompted with the list of disk drives and partitions. I immediately noticed something is wrong with partition sizes and also noticed strange partition names (having a word *raid*). Of course, seeing this, I did not want to proceed any further. I've taken my time to take pictures of the listing to have it as a reference and compare it to the configuration displayed in Windows environment. This way, I would've been able to try to figure out why Ubuntu is not reading partitions correctly.

[image: Ubuntu displaying partitions: screen 1]

[image: Ubuntu displaying partitions: screen 2]

After this, I exited the installer and rebooted into Windows. Note that I **did not** continue any further with the installation, nor clicked any other buttons.

After the restart, I booted into Windows. Windows took particularly long time to boot up, working at the screen with the blue Windows logo.

Upon logging in, I was able to see only **Disk 1** partitions in a file manager. Inspecting *Disk Management* tool, I noticed that it was actually **Disk 0** that held **S** and **T** partitions now and that **Disk 1** is offline due to it having the exact same signature as **Disk 0**.

Further on, I tried disconnecting one disk at a time, only to find out that **Disk 0**'s partitions and data themselves were now exact copies of **Disk 1**. Since **Disk 1** was full at the time, **Disk 0** was completely rewritten, therefore irreversibly deleting complete set of data I had there.

### What went wrong?

After the loss of crucial data (I did have backups of some of them, but not entirely) and a long stare at the wall in front of me, I'm still wondering what went wrong.

I'm aware that what's done is done and cannot be reverted, but I cannot but ask myself what could possibly went wrong and **why (and how) did Ubuntu mark these partitions as RAID**. I cannot be 100% sure, but I think it's Windows who did the actual rewriting during a long boot after exiting the installer, but it was certainly led to do so by Ubuntu forcing disk drives to become RAID configured. **And how is this even possible when RAID mode is not configured in BIOS?** Note that my Windows-based PC has been running happily for 6 years without problems before this.

Any help and insight into this would be appreciated. I'm posting this mainly to try to come up with a sensible solution and also to warn people that there is something seriously wrong with the installer (or live distribution perhaps), a bug that must not be left unattended.